# Diverging random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have a process $X_{n+1} = X_n\xi_n$ where $\xi_n\sim\mathcal N(1,1)$ and $\xi_n$ is independent of $X_n$. I need to prove that if $X_0\neq0$ then
$$
\mathsf P\{|X_n|>1\text{ for some }n\geq0\} = 1.
$$
From this I construct a random walk: $Y_n = \log|X_n|$ so
$$
Y_{n+1} = Y_n+\eta_n
$$
where $\eta_n = \log|\xi_n|$. I guess that from here I should apply the Law of Large Numbers - but I'm stacked with it. Could you help me? For now I should prove that $Y_n$ will eventually be positive a.s. starting from any point.

On the other hand, $X_n$ is a martingale which maybe also useful for deriving the desired result. If it helps, one can take $\xi_n\sim\mathcal N(m,1)$ for some $m\geq1$.

Comment: Are you sure that the normal is $\mathcal N(1,1)$ (mean 1)?

Comment: Yes, it's not a misprint.

Comment: The random variable $\log|\xi|$ **is** integrable.

Comment: @Didier: Sorry, you're right.

Comment: So your question reduces to determining whether $E\log|\xi|$ is $\ge0$ (you win) or $<0$ (you lose).

Comment: @Didier: for $m=1$ it seems to me I lost. Could you please tell me the way of proof if $E\log|\xi|\geq 0$?

Comment: WolframAlpha? Yes you lose for $m=1$, but you win for $m\ge1.3$ or something, though.

Comment: Sure, but for $m=2$ it thinks for 15 minutes already. Anyway, what about the proof for $m>1.3$?

Comment: No it does not: integral(log(x)*(exp(-(x-2)^2/2)+exp(-(x+2)^2/2)),x=0..infinity) yields 1.30433 in about two seconds.

Comment: @Didier: Does the way of taking this integral matter for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didier Piau perfectly showed an equivalence of this problem and unboundness of a random walk and also gave a solution for the latter problem in this question: [When random walk is upper unbounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49631/when-random-walk-is-upper-unbounded)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$E(x_{n} | x_{n-1}) = x_{n-1} E(\xi_{n}) = x_{n-1}$

$E(x_n) = E( E(x_{n} | x_{n-1})) = E(x_{n-1})$

Hence  $E(x_n)=x_0$

Doing the same for $E(x_n^2)$ we can show that the variance tends to infinity with $n$. Then, <s>you are done</s> (we are *not* done, we need more than this).

Comment: Do you mean I should apply Chebyshev inequality?

Comment: MMmm no, come to think of it, we need something stronger than that.  For example, a Cauchy variable has infinite variance but the probability that it's modulus is above 1 is certainly not 1. So my "you're done" sentence is false.

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between the $\xi_n$ sequence and the $X_n$ sequence? The statement is clearly false when $\xi_n = 1/X_n$.

Comment: I assume $\xi_n$ is independent of $x_n$

Comment: Yes, they are. Edited.

Comment: Is the r.v. $\xi_n$ independent of r.v. $X_n$ or the sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ independent of the sequence $\{X_n\}$? These are different conditions. Also, are the $\xi_n$ assumed to be i.i.d? Again, the statement can be false if the $\xi_n$ have some sort of relationship among themselves.

Comment: $\xi_n\perp \mathcal F_n = \sigma\{X_k,k\leq n\}$ and $\xi_n$ are iid r.v.